# Wiki xml parser - org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable

Tags: scala, serialization, apache-spark

I am newbie to both scala and spark, and trying some of the tutorials, this one is from Advanced Analytics with Spark. The following code is supposed to work:

```
import com.cloudera.datascience.common.XmlInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.io._
val path = "/home/petr/Downloads/wiki/wiki"
val conf = new Configuration()
conf.set(XmlInputFormat.START_TAG_KEY, "<page>")
conf.set(XmlInputFormat.END_TAG_KEY, "</page>")
val kvs = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(path, classOf[XmlInputFormat],
classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text], conf)

val rawXmls = kvs.map(p => p._2.toString)

import edu.umd.cloud9.collection.wikipedia.language._
import edu.umd.cloud9.collection.wikipedia._

def wikiXmlToPlainText(xml: String): Option[(String, String)] = {
val page = new EnglishWikipediaPage()
WikipediaPage.readPage(page, xml)
if (page.isEmpty) None
else Some((page.getTitle, page.getContent))
}

val plainText = rawXmls.flatMap(wikiXmlToPlainText)
```

But it gives

```
scala> val plainText = rawXmls.flatMap(wikiXmlToPlainText)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:158)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1622)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.flatMap(RDD.scala:295)
...
```

Running Spark v1.3.0 on a local (and I have loaded only about a 21MB of the wiki articles, just to test it).

All of https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=org.apache.spark.SparkException%3A+Task+not+serializable didn't get me any clue...

Thanks.

Comment: How are you running this code? This is not a self-contained, valid Scala class. Try to put this into an `object` definition with a `main` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
    import com.cloudera.datascience.common.XmlInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.io._
val path = "/home/terrapin/Downloads/enwiki-20150304-pages-articles1.xml-p000000010p000010000"
val conf = new Configuration()
conf.set(XmlInputFormat.START_TAG_KEY, "<page>")
conf.set(XmlInputFormat.END_TAG_KEY, "</page>")
val kvs = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(path, classOf[XmlInputFormat],
classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text], conf)
val rawXmls = kvs.map(p => p._2.toString)


import edu.umd.cloud9.collection.wikipedia.language._
import edu.umd.cloud9.collection.wikipedia._


val plainText = rawXmls.flatMap{line =>
val page = new EnglishWikipediaPage()
WikipediaPage.readPage(page, line)
if (page.isEmpty) None
else Some((page.getTitle, page.getContent))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first guess which comes to mind is that: all your code is wrapped in the object where `SparkContext` is defined. Spark tries to serialize this object to transfer `wikiXmlToPlainText` function to nodes. Try to create different object with the only one function `wikiXmlToPlainText`.